# Keras "fit_generator" throws "The Session graph is empty. Add operations to the graph before calling run()."

Tags: flask, keras

I'm training a LSTM encoder-decoder model using Keras `fit_generator`.

Everything works fine when I run the file as a stand alone program.

I'm trying to make it into a REST api using Python flask. When I send the request the program halts at the `fit_generator()` function call on model and throws:

> The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before
>   calling run().

Tried storing `graph = tf.get_default_graph()` after model creation and using it while calling `fi_generator` with: `graph.as_default(): fit_generator()`

but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Would you please post your code as well? It's really hard to say anything without seeing your code.